# How deactivate default category for current post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories, taxonomy-terms

I am use `wp_set_post_categories` and `wp_set_post_terms`, but I cann't deactivate  **Uncategorized** category.

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array(), 'category', false );
```

Comment: Shed more light on how exactly you are using those methods?

Comment: wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array(), 'category', false );

Comment: It's my mistake. It's work:
**- wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array(), 'category', false );**
**- wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array(), 'category', false );**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my mistake. It's work:

```
- wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array(), 'category', false ); 
- wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array(), 'category', false );
```